# For loop with multi-line body

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to define a list of directories e.g. *"dir1", "dir2"* and then for each of those directories execute a couple of actions, eg:

- `xcopy C:\test\*.dll  D:\%%le_dir%%\dll  /Y`
- `xcopy C:\test\*.exe  D:\%%le_dir%%\exe  /Y`
- where `le_dir` is a directory from the defined list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (the list is in a text file):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do (
xcopy "C:\test\*.exe" "D:\%%i\exe" /Y
xcopy "C:\test\*.dll" "D:\%%i\dll" /Y
)
```

Put the destination folders in a text file `list.txt`:

```
dir1
dir2
...
```

Edit1 (folders are defined in the script):

```
set "folders=dir1 dir2 dir3"
for %%i in (%folders%) do (
xcopy "C:\test\*.exe" "D:\%%i\exe" /Y
xcopy "C:\test\*.dll" "D:\%%i\dll" /Y
)
```

Edit2 (if there are spaces in folder names):

```
set "folders="dir 1" "dir 2" "dir 3""
for %%i in (%folders%) do (
xcopy "C:\test\*.exe" "D:\%%~i\exe" /Y
xcopy "C:\test\*.dll" "D:\%%~i\dll" /Y
)
```

Edit3: ")" added.

Comment: what is list.txt? Can the array of directories be defined in the script?

Comment: The destination folders are defined in a seperate text file `list.txt`.

Comment: okay. This is very nice, but could you specify a way to have those dirs inline ,like `set DIRS=...`;

Comment: Yes, you can modify the loop: 

`set "folders=dir1 dir2 dir3"`
`for %%i in (%folders%) do (`

Comment: BTW. what if folders have spaces in names? :(

Comment: lol, you separate bare words with empty strings? what a nice syntax.. :D